# Create a wrapper for external API calls

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I need to consume an external API from an L5.1 app. So far, I already installed Guzzle (6.0), stored the API url in the `.env` file and inside the `app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php` I made this:

```php
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

abstract class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    protected $API;

    public function __construct() {

        // Init API Client
        $this->API = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
            'base_uri' => env('API_URL'),
            'http_errors' => false, // false = http errors won't throw Exceptions
            'headers' => [
                'User-Agent' => env('API_UA'),
                'Accept'     => 'application/json',        
            ]
        ]);                     

    }
}
```

This way I can make an API call in any controller like this:

```php
$call = $this->API->get('users/getAll');
if($call->getStatusCode() != 200 || $call === null){
    $data = ["errors" => "There was an error retrieving the users."];
}else{
    $data = json_decode($call->getBody());
}

return view('users.list', $data);
```

It works, but as you can see, I would need to do some checks for every API call.

What would be a valid approach to create a wrapper that has all the logic, so I can use it like this:

```php
$data = $this->API->get('users/getAll');

return view('users.list', $data);
```

I was looking at Providers and Packages as possible solutions but, truth be told, I am a bit confused with the info I find on Laravel docs and the Internet.

Also, since this is an internal project (in Company) I guess the Package approach is not the recommended way since it has to be published on packagist (AFAIK).

**UPDATE**

I finally went for the "package" option. After a bit of research and a bit of trial and error, I ended up crafting a package that met my needs.

I'll try to make the package more generic and publish it to packagist, hoping it might be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

You could setup Guzzle so that it throws an exception in case of error. This is the "http_errors" parameter in your constructor, which you would need to set to "true".

You can then have some global handler to handle all exceptions in the same way. Look at [set_exception_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) for this.

I think that would make the code a lot simpler, and you can still catch individual exception when needed, by wrapping the call in a try/catch block.

Comment: What I need is to separate the logic (validations, parsing, etc) in a "Laravel" way, like Packages / Providers / Contracts do.